# loading activity dynamically shows up a blank screen first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

HI I am loading a dynamic activity based on if the user is logged in or not. I search through internet and got a solution which asks to create a blank activity, check the condition in oncreate, start new activity based on the condition and finish the blank activity. 
However, this shows me a blank white screen for 1-2 seconds. How do I avoid it?

(I have deleted the default layout when the blank activity is created.)

Here is my code:

```
public class BlankActivity extends Activity {
    public  SharedPreferences mStoredValues;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent loadIntent;
        mStoredValues = getSharedPreferences(Constants.STORED_VALUES, 0);
        if (mStoredValues.contains(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
            loadIntent = new Intent(BlankActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
        }   
        else {
            loadIntent = new Intent(BlankActivity.this, Login.class);
        }
        startActivity(loadIntent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

Here are the activity details in Manifest file.

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrus.citruspay.BlankActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: You can't really avoid the delay. However you could inflate a layout containing a progress bar or a splash screen which is a better user experience than a white screen.

Comment: maybe you should not divide it into 3 screens (blank, login and homescreen) but use one that will either present itself or show another e.g. start with homescreen if logged then dont have to do anything if login required you can open login page (or even login in the popup above homescreen).

Answer (score 1):

You should use Fragments to cover this situation. You can choose which fragment you add in your activity dynamically. Try something like this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    mStoredValues = getSharedPreferences(Constants.STORED_VALUES, 0);
    Fragment fragment;
    if (mStoredValues.contains(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        fragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
    }   
    else {
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_id,fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` to your first activity tag in the manifest and see.

```
 <activity  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:name="com.citrus.citruspay.BlankActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: it still is there for a while.

Comment: which makes this white invisible - not good for responsiveness, maybe better to utilise this screen and have a sort of splash screen?

Comment: how does facebook do it? They don't show a splash screen everytime. If I am logged in, they will show the wall directly.

Comment: in facebook also you will be getting that white screen for a couple of seconds